# JSP page cached even after providing cache parameters

Tags: java, spring, jsp, caching

The project is running on Spring framework and the Handler class which the request is handled extends MultiActionController.

I added the following code to set the Cache-Control params in Response Header.

```
httpServletResponse.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must- revalidate,max-age=0,private,pre-check=0,post-check=0"); 
httpServletResponse.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
httpServletResponse.addDateHeader("Expires", -1);
```

Even ,in the JSP page,i included the following lines:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="private" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="pre-check=0" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="post-check=0" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
```

When i debug the page on fire fox using Firebug,the response header is being shown as below:

[image]

and the cache tab as below:

[image]

This case is happening only with one page,remaining pages are not getting cached.What is the reason for this?Please help me to sort it out.

Comment: What makes you believe that it is still being cached. Both Reponse Header and Cache tab has Expires which is in the past. So it will always load from Server not browser. Any other observations you made?

Comment: I checked the same on Chrome browser unser chrome://cache/ I can see the cached JSP page there. :( And on click of browser back button,thge cached page is getting loaded(No separate request has been sent)

Comment: I have same issue but its running in my case.
nwys try Change Pragma capital P to pragma

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching_FAQ. Here is the important part:

> The mozilla cache holds all documents downloaded via HTTP by the user.
>   At first this may seem odd; however, this is done to make visited
>   documents available for back/forward, saving, viewing-as-source, etc.
>   without requiring an additional trip to the server. It likewise
>   improves offline browsing of cached content.